# Moving Sharepoint 3.0 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008

I'm moving our Sharepoint site 3.0 2007 from a Windows server 2003 machine to windows server 2008 RC2.  The Sharepoint site uses a sql database which will also be moved to the new server.   I need to move all site content included any documents that have been uploaded to the site and the sql database.

Is there any easy way to simply backup the site and the restore it on the new server? or do I need to backup and restore the sql database separately?

Will backing up and restoring the site move uploaded documents as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to backup the SQL database separately. If customizations have been done on SharePoint site 3.0 then you need to consider it as well because for customized developments/deployments you have to prepare the destination machine as well.

Comment: The central administrator has a backup/restore function which includes a full backup option.  Can I use this to move the site instead of using the command line?

Comment: Yes, definitely you can use that option. Again custom deployed assemblies should not go in the backup automatically. If custom packages are deployed then you shall have to take them yourself.

Comment: that sounds great, i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backing up and restoring will certainly move your documents
2. You can do a catastrophic back up and restore, which will take all of your data

Comment: How do I do a catastrophic backup? so that will backup my sql database as well and restore it automatically one the new server?

Comment: it's one of the options under stsadm -o backup for instance